# Perform Dot Product on Both Side of the Equation

Tags: vectors

the question is find the value of x from
$$p\vec{x} + (\vec{x}×\vec{a})=\vec{b}.$$

in this question can i do scalar product on both the sides of the equation like
$$p\vec{x}·\vec{x}+\vec{x}·(\vec{x}×\vec{a})=\vec{x}·\vec{b}$$

and then
$$ p\vec{x}·\vec{x}=\vec{x}·\vec{b}$$
$$p\vec{x}·\vec{x}-\vec{x}·\vec{b}=0$$
$$\vec{x}(p\vec{x}-\vec{b})=0$$

and then find the value of $$\vec{x}$$

Comment: Please see this post for a guide on how to use MathJax on MSE: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: i did not understand it

Comment: Analysis is correct.

Comment: but in the solution we were provided the answer contained the term a as well which is missing in the answer through this way

Answer (score 0):

When $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are non-collinear, we can let $\vec x=u \vec a+ v \vec b + w \vec a \times \vec b$, insert it in the given Eq,
$$pu \vec a+p v \vec b + p w \vec a \times \vec b+(u \vec a+ v \vec b + w \vec a \times \vec b)\times \vec a =\vec b$$
use $$(\vec a \times \vec b) \times \vec a=-
\vec a \times (\vec a \times \vec b)=-[(\vec a. \vec b) \vec a-a^2 \vec b].$$
We get $$\vec a [p u -w(\vec a, \vec b)]+\vec b[pv+w a^2]+\vec a \times \vec b [w-vp]=\vec b$$
Comparing coefficients of $\vec a, \vec b. \vec c$ on both sides we get $$v=pw, w=\frac{1}{p^2+a^2}, u=\frac{\vec a . \vec b}{p^2+a^2}.$$
Finally, $$\vec x=\frac{\vec a. \vec b}{p^2+a^2} \vec a+\frac{p\vec b}{p^2+a^2}+\frac{\vec a \times \vec b}{p(p^2+a^2)}$$

Comment: The derivation neglected p.

Comment: @herb steinberg thanks I have corrected it now.

Comment: I have understood the way you solved the problem I just wanted to know, if there was something wrong with the way i did the problem which leads to the answer b(vector)/p that is the vector is parallel to b vector, which is clearly not the case

Comment: You may do right things but may not get the right anwser. This means your strategy has failed. I have solved it by a general method. You should check if my final answer is right. There is one more method which I may do later if I get time.

Comment: yes this is the right answer but actually my question was why this method does not work?

Comment: @Vishakh Prakas see my seond answer posted here below. $\vec r. \vec a=w$ one cannot find $\vec r$ directly. It is not aa=w so $r =w/a$

Answer (score 0):

$$p\vec x +(\vec x\times \vec a)=\vec b~~~(1)$$
Dot Eq.(1) with $\vec a$, to get
$$p (\vec a.\vec x)+ [\vec a, \vec x, \vec a]=\vec a. \vec b \implies (\vec a. \vec x)= \frac{(\vec a. \vec b)}{p}~~~~(2)$$
Cross Equation (1) with $\vec a$, then
$$p(\vec a \times \vec x)+\vec a \times (\vec x \times \vec a)=\vec a \times \vec b~~~~~(3)$$
$$p(\vec a \times \vec x)+ a^2 \vec x-(\vec a. \vec x) \vec a=\vec a \times \vec b~~~~~(4)$$
Using (1) and (2), we can write
$$p(p\vec x-\vec b)+a^2 \vec x-\frac{(\vec a. \vec b) \vec a }{p}=\vec a \times \vec b.$$
We finally get
$$\vec x=\frac{\vec a. \vec b}{p(p^2+a^2)} \vec a+\frac{p\vec b}{p^2+a^2}+\frac{\vec a \times \vec b}{p^2+a^2}$$